# geoserver world image publishing error (georeferenced by ArcMap)

Tags: raster, geoserver, arcgis-10.2, georeferencing, raster-conversion

I want to add store - WorldImage in geoserver 2.5, but I still get this error:

*"Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: Failed to create reader from file:data/picture.jpg and hints null"*

According to manual at http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/worldimage.html I only have to provide .jpg + .jgw (or .tif + .tfw).

Here they write ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file ) that I have to provide .prj file together with jgw (which is only transformation info, not projection) and jpg.

*World files do not specify a coordinate system; this information is generally stored somewhere else in the raster file itself or in another companion file, e.g. Esri's .prj file.*

I create my "picture.jpg" in ArcMap with georeferencing panel (update/rectify functions). It is weird that sometimes I get a result as a four files and sometimes only three (but still different) :

Case 1:
picture1.**jgw**
picture1.**jpg**
picture1.**jpg.aux.xml**

Case 2:
picture2.**jgwx** (different file ending!)
picture2.jpg
picture2.jpg.aux.xml

Case 3:
picture3.jgw
picture3.jpg
picture3.jpg.aux.xml
picture3.**jpg.ovr** (this file is here new!)

Is problem here (ArcMap 10.2) or is it in geoserver? As a next step I would like to publish my rasters as WMTS using Openlayers. Geotiffs are much larger than jpegs, so I am trying to use world images.

Comment: Geotiffs do not need to be any larger than jpegs because tiff is a wrapper format. The data inside tiff can be compressed with jpeg method. See compression options from http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html. For creating .prj file for your images save some shapefile to the same projection and copy and rename the .prj part to suit the name of the image file.

Comment: Hi. I have managed to publish my rasters (from JPEG/TIFF converted to transparent alpha channel PNG with up to 64 colours - this resulted to almost same size files as if I used JPEG or transparent JPEG2000). My files are historical maps, so they dont need too much true colour as if I published some kind of imaginery... But I still have problems with defining geoserver's NATIVE SRS using PRJ file. Geoserver is still writing that I have plain 2D SRS. Solution where I should overwrite configuration inside data/workspace/... XML file isn't ideal in case when I have tens or hunders of rasters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So,
georeferencing panel in ArcMap provides 2 options - update georeferencing and rectify.
Update georeferencing creates jgwx, pnwx, tfwx extensions and this can't be opened in GeoServer. A solution is to rectify all images, which creates pgw-like extensions.

To define a world file's projection in GeoServer you have to make an exact copy of projection definition from layer setup to new file with "SameNameAsLayer.prj" name and extension.

Comment: This was hugely helpful to me... after georeferencing tons of historic maps, I hadn't nailed down this distinction.  Thanks!

Comment: also, I'm finding that if you export the image from the table of contents, rather choose the rectify option from the georeferencing menu, you avoid getting the black collar that fills out the square of a tilted image.  This is useful for me because I'm filtering the white/light gray tones to leave a black line drawing with transparent background.

Comment: I also had problems with getting "black collar" around my images with rectify function. This resulted in errors in geoserver and no transparency in my image. I found that with "OSGeo4W Shell" you can use "gdalinfo MyRectifiedImage.png" to get image+projection informations. There is also color table for as much colors as your image has (0:143,121,71,255 - some color; 1:...; ...; 15: 255,255,255,0 = white fully transparent) and my solution was to set NoData to this number and then I get right images. Exporting from table of contents maybe automatically sets NoData as last color from color table